# Dovecot - [IN-USE] Internal error occurred

Tags: debian, dovecot

I have Debian 7.3 VPS with Webmin, Apache, MySQL, PHP and Postfix and DOvecot for handing emails.

Throughout Webmins "read user mail" option, I can send/receive emails, but it looks ugly and it is not practical and not very usefull.
So I installed Roundcube and tried to login and got this message: "Login failed."

So I go to terminal and entered:

```
# terminal localhost pop3
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.

user myusername

+OK

pass mypassword

-ERR [IN-USE] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And there I stuck.

Log doesn't tell me something usefull.

```
# grep -i dovecot /var/log/syslog

Jan 23 00:22:52 MyHOstName dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<admin@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
Jan 23 00:23:05 MyHOstName dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (tried to use disallowed plaintext auth): user=<>, rip=XXX.X.XX.XXX, lip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX, session=<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

What I should do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't post your configuration, so we can't really tell.  But  http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms might help.

Comment: what about /var/log/maillog ?

Comment: /var/log/maillog: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear why the pop3 log in is failing. The connection is being made without encryption and dovecot's default configuration prohibits unencrypted, plaintext logins. However, I'd recommend against pop3 if we can fix your imap issue.

The IMAP is a different story because it is connecting with encryption. I don't know if it's safe to assume your IMAP setup is otherwise ok because I'm assuming you were describing using webmin as a regular webmail client. (Webmin has a different, "read user mail" plugin which is not relevant here.)

My best guess is the mydomain.com attached to the username is throwing it off. I suspect you need the statement 'username_format = %n' in your passdb and userdb {} stanzas.

To connect and test your pop3 example above properly, use the openssl command like this:

```
  openssl s_client -starttls pop3 -connect <server>:110
```

Dovecot even has a handy-dandy utility for testing/debugging this. Check out doveadm-auth.

```
 http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Auth
```

I hope this helps. This has more details on debugging/testing. http://wiki2.dovecot.org/TestInstallation

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your advice about openssl commandline, it connects to the server but then -ERR [IN-USE] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
closed